# Отличие изменяемго от неизменяемого типа

Tags: python, python-3.x

В стандартной статье про отличие изменяемых типов от неизменяемых было сказано, что при обновлении значения переменной ей просто присваивается другой идентификатор. А вот про этот момент не писали:

```
a = '12'# или другой любой неизменяемый тип данных
b = '12'
print(id(a), id(b))
print(a == b, a is b)
#2172494540912 2172494540912
#True True

a = []# или другой любой изменяемый тип данных
b = []
print(id(a), id(b))
print(a == b, a is b)
#2213877772480 2213877772544
#True False
```

Я не понимаю, почему так происходит и зачем это нужно. Мое предположение такое: раз неизменяемый тип нельзя изменить, то при его "изменении" создается новый, и будет без разницы, если идентификаторы совпадают, а изменяемый тип данных при изменении как бы заденет другой такой же объект и получится ерунда. Или почему так, можете подсказать?

Comment: python кэширует небольшие строки и числа для их возможного дальнейшего использования в целях экономии памяти. И если какому-то еще объекту присваивается эта строка или число, то он просто создает ссылку на этот же объект. Если взять строку подлиннее, символов в 50, то она кэшироваться уже не будет. Это все хорошо описано у Лутца.

Comment: <Большое спасибо. Я попробовал, но и большие строки хэшируются. И как я понимаю, то о чем вы говорили называется коллизией? И еще один вопрос, зачем вы оставили не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: Язык надо (для начала, имею в виду) учить по российским университетским учебникам, рекомендованным Министерством, а не по статьям:-) Здесь вы работаете с интернированными объектами, В СPython целые числа от - 5 до 256 -  интернированные объекты. Как и большая часть строк до 20 символов длиной.

Comment: Для ответа маловато информации, по хорошему еще описать как работает изменение переменных, указывающих на неизменяемые объекты, и как работают переменные, указывающие на изменяемые объекты. Но у Лутца это всё хорошо и полно расписано )

Comment: Вообще надо указывать с какой средой вы работаете, в разных средах оптимизация по-разному будет выполняться. В каких-то случаях и длинные строки будут средой интернироваться. Принцип от этого не меняется.

Comment: "или другой любой неизменяемый тип данных" - вот это вот сильно прям )))  возьмите кортежи `(1,2)`, например - кортеж тип не изменяемый, а `id` уже не совпадут )  короче да, тут речь скорее про оптимизацию, в частности про интернирование строк и не только

Answer (score 0):

Равные значения неизменяемого типа могут иметь разные `id`. Например строки:

```
a = '12'
b = (a + ' ')[:-1]
print(id(a), id(b))
print(a == b, a is b)
```

> ```
> 140166958357744 140166957655664
> True False
> ```

Или числа:

```
a = 300
b = 300 - a + a
print(id(a), id(b))
print(a == b, a is b)
```

> ```
> 139934013266096 139934013275824
> True False
> ```

Интерпретатор Питона следит за копиями и иногда надо постараться чтобы его обвести вокруг пальца.

Comment: Для 300 и так id будет разный, даже без манипуляций. По крайней мере в колабе, например )  А для 200 id будет одинаковый и манипуляции такие не помогут, питон их упростит ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, без манипуляций в коде `a = 300; b = 300` компилятор создаст только одну константу. В нём есть несколько эвристик упрощающих константные выражения и переиспользующие их. Если компилятор (не интерпретатор) сможет вычислить два числа и они будут равны, он создаст только одну константу.

Comment: Вы проверяли? Интересно, какая версия питона. Обычно от -5 до 256 только интернируются. В колабе будет True False

Comment: @CrazyElf, Python 3.10: `@>>> a = 300; b = 300; id(a); id(b)` -> `140546710951600`, `140546710951600`.